# Name for value which may only be -1, 0 or 1?

Tags: terminology

Is there a name for a value which may only be -1, 0 or 1?

Is there a name for a function which creates such a value from arbitrary numbers?

It would be implemented like this:

T Function( T value ) {
  return ( value < 0 ) ? -1 : ( value > 0 ) ? 1 :0;
}

Comment: Standard rules apply: If you need a name for it, make up a name and define your terms before first use.

Comment: Probably "sign" could be a suggestion.

Comment: java.lang.Math.signum() in Java. Math.Sign() in C#. Math.sign() in JavaScript. Hmm, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986152/why-doesnt-python-have-a-sign-function) or [numpy.sign](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) in Python.

Comment: There is no common term for such a value.

Comment: @Hendrik: Thanks, Sign() also is a good name!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard name, but the value can be seen as value in the [balanced ternary numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/balanced_ternary) or as the [sign (sgn) function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/sign_function). IMHO, the name Sign() is more appropriate when working with calculations or ordering, the 'balanced ternary' is more appropriate when working with logic. For my purposes, I created a Tri enum in the C# language and, besides others, a generic mapping function with this code:

```
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function
    public static Tri Sgn<T>( this T value ) where T : IComparable<T> {
        var t = value.CompareTo( default( T ) );
        return t < 0 ? Tri.Negative : t > 0 ? Tri.Positive : Tri.Zero;
    }
```

And, last but not least, there is the three-valued logic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/three-valued_logic. Values of the 'Tri' type can be used to implement functions for three-valued logic.

Comment: FWIW, the well-known C++ Boost libraries call this type a [tribool](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/tribool.html).

Comment: This is a good answer and you should feel free to accept it. That helps the system too because the question then shows as "settled".